# Is there a reason not to use Strict mode in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have been wondering, without any specific context to this question, is there a reason not to use strict mode in JavaScript? I have hardly ever been working without it in JS and from all the reading I've done on the subject it seems purely beneficial as unsupported browsers just ignore the statement,  but if that is the case, why don't browsers always use strict mode in the first place?

Comment: No, there is no reason not to use it. You gave yourself the answer :) - note that you should use it not in global scope, just in your scope, otherwise you could break features from imported code!

Comment: when both of them can coexist why do you want to do that

Comment: @Arun Killu : to my understanding, strict mode exists to remove issues associated with how relaxed JavaScript standards were so always requiring it would lead to generally cleaner code. My understanding might be wrong tho, thus the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have been wondering, without any specific context to this question, is there a reason not to use strict mode in JavaScript?

That is rather subjective.

> I have hardly ever been working without it in JS and from all the reading I've done on the subject it seems purely beneficial as unsupported browsers just ignore the statement, but if that is the case, why don't browsers always use strict mode in the first place?

Because if a page uses JavaScript that depends on features of non-strict mode, that code will break.

Strict mode is not 100% backwards compatible. That is why it is has to be turned on by the person writing the JS.

Comment: That is precisesly what's confusing me: Strict mode seems to resolve a lot of genuine issues that JavaScript has, at least from my perspective and from what I have red (after all, most articles about strict mode are written by people enthusiastic about the feature, and thus are quite positive in their view of this issue.) Is that not the case? Can it end up being too limiting, or removing essential features of the language?

Comment: Code written before strict mode existed would probably not work.